# Parsing JSON with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON that looks like the following:

```
[{
    "Age": 35,
    "FirstName": "Peyton",
    "LastName": "Manning"
  },
  {
    "Age": 31,
    "FirstName": "Drew",
    "LastName": "Brees"
  },
  {
    "Age": 58,
    "FirstName": "Brett",
    "LastName": "Favre"
  }
]
```

This JSON is passed into a function I have created called parseJSON. This function looks like this:

```
function parseJSON(result)
{
  $.each(result.items,function(i,item) {
    alert("First Name: " + item.FirstName);
    alert("Age: " + item.Age);
  });
}
```

When I run this code though, I get a JavaScript error that says "G is undefined". How do I parse my JSON with JQuery such that I can read the FirstName and Age properties?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Most simple parse JSON by native JS:

```
function parseJSON(result)
{
  for(var i in result) {
    var item = result[i];
    alert("First Name: " + item.FirstName);
    alert("Age: " + item.Age);
  } 
}
```

Comment: I agreed, bypass jQuery entirely

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working function that uses your sample case.

```
var result = [{
    "Age": 35,
    "FirstName": "Peyton",
    "LastName": "Manning"
}, {
    "Age": 31,
    "FirstName": "Drew",
    "LastName": "Brees"
}, {
    "Age": 58,
    "FirstName": "Brett",
    "LastName": "Favre"
}];

function parseJSON(result){
    $.each(result, function(index, object){
        $.each(object, function(i, o){
            alert(i + " = " + o);
        })
    })
}

parseJSON(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable called `result` that doesn't exist in your function.  Perhaps, it should be replaced with `json`.

```
function parseJSON(json) 
{ 
  $.each(json,function(i,item) { 
    alert("First Name: " + item.FirstName); 
    alert("Age: " + item.Age); 
  }); 
}
```

**EDIT**: based on your update, I think it's because you are referencing a property on result that doesn't exist, namely `items`.  The null value being passed into the each function is causing jQuery to choke on an internal function.

Comment: Nope. The object doesn't have an `items` property. It's simply an array of objects. Each object has an `Age`, `FirstName`, etc. property, so I think it is correct as I have it.  -- this was in response to a comment that it should be `json.items` instead of simply `json`.

Comment: I should also add that I'm assuming that it isn't a string, i.e., the json string has already been "objectified."

Comment: How should changing a variable name fix any problems?

Comment: @naugtur -- check the edit history on the question.  Originally, the function didn't have result in it.  You're downvoting me because my answer reflected the OP's omission.

Comment: That's a big "excuse me" then. I'll make it up for You.

Comment: I've edited my post here so you can change your vote, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check your complete code, not only the sample shown here for "G". I suppose, there is a syntax error somewhere.
As to the use of "result" - it could be a global variable, but tvanfosson is right I think. Doesn't look good here.

Comment: I think G is probably an internal jQuery function after minification.

Answer (score 0):

From [json.org](http://json.org): [json_sans_eval](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/). This parses a JSON string without the hazards of using `eval`.